# Pyramid with more than one characters not working

Tags: python

i have this simple Pyramid. It works like this:
1.You input a number and a/or multiple characters
2.You will receive a print that will show your number multiplied by the character. The table will be displayed as a pyramid.

I was thinking of getting the Len() of the string and then i have no idea what else i could do with it to get it aligned right.

```
Problem : If you do 5 G
    G
   GG
  GGG
 GGGG
GGGGG

But if you do 5 GG
   GG
 GGGG
GGGGGG
GGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
```

My rjust doesn't seems to do the trick for this.

---

```
import sys


def pyramide(nbr, char):
    resultat = ''
    for i in range(0, nbr+1):
        resultat += (nbr * str('') + int(i) * str(char) + "\n").rjust(nbr+1)
    return resultat

def main():
    nbr = int(sys.argv[1])
    char = (sys.argv[2])
    message = pyramide(nbr, char)
    print(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Inputting multiple characters doesn't match the requirement of "You input a number and a character", so I'm not surprised that it doesn't work.

Comment: but i want it to align even if the user would enter multiple characters

Comment: change rjust(nbr+1) to rjust(len(char)*nbr+1)

Comment: woa thanks, i though about it but i didnt know how to write it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, i'm having a problem with the same code.... it's actual adding a space at the beginning of the program and i have no idea how i can remove it. Do you have any cue? I know it has to do with the \n in the loop.

Comment: Oh i found my solution it was because i didn't start my range at 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by adding the prespacing, then I add in the amount of characters:

```
def pyramide(size, char):
    resultat = ''
    for i in range(0, size):
        resultat  += (' ' * (size-i)) + (char * int(i*2+1)) + '\n'
    return resultat
```

Comment: I used the solution just above from Shipping. Less change of code :)

Comment: resultat += (nbr * str('') + int(i) * str(char) + "\n").rjust(len(char)*nbr+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `format` to center:

```
def pyramide(nbr, char):
    resultat = ''
    for i in range(0, nbr+1):
        chars = char * int(i*2+1)
        resultat += '{:^30}'.format(chars) + '\n'
    return resultat
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples