# isosceles triangle python that must return a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked all over the the website and I can't seem to find anyone that has had to do a similar problem as mine.  I'm supposed to create a function that prints an asterisk isosceles triangle in python 3.X here is an example of what its supposed to look like and the hint that was given

"Hint: Do not print out the triangle. You have to use newline character to create the newline between 2 levels"

```
triangle(0) --> ''
triangle(1) --> '*'
triangle(2) -->
*
**
triangle(3) -->
*
**
***
```

i know how to create the triangle because there are many question threads on here about it, but im not sure how to return a string that creates it.

heres what i was given as a starting point

```
def triangle(levels):
  result_str = ''
  return result_str

print(triangle(3))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyramid with more than one characters not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243703/pyramid-with-more-than-one-characters-not-working)

Comment: Instead of printing a triangle directly, concatenate the lines together

Comment: @AndreySobolev thats the problem, im having a hard time figuring out how to write it all out lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean :

```
def triangle(levels):
    result_str = ''
    for i in range(levels + 1)
        result_str += '*' * i + '\n'
    return result_str

print(triangle(3))
```

test failed

```
Tests failed in  TriangleTestCase.test_2  
Fail: expected 
*
**
***
to be equal to  got *
**
***
```

Comment: yeah, but for some reason its failing all the tests.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Tests failed in  TriangleTestCase.test_2  
Fail: expected 
*
**
***
 to be equal to  got *
**
***

Comment: Also i want to encourage you do do your own reaserch and practice, you 'll learn much more.

Comment: i know, when i retrieve the answers from somewhere else I don't just blindly copy paste and call it a day, i take the time to look at it and go over it and understand it.. maybe i like problem solving less than i originally thought i did lol

Comment: String concatenation is quite easy to understand .  Use the `+` operator to join two strings : `'te' + 'st' = 'test'` . The `*` operator does the same thing many times : `'a' * 3 = 'aaa'` . Its not that hard, just keep trying.

Comment: by the way, what does result_str = '' actually mean? is it just an empty string?

Comment: i understand concatenation, its the for loop thats got me sort of confused.. especially where it says  levels + 1

Answer (score 0):

So you want to include a newline character in the string?

I don't know exactly what you do not know. but

newline character is ' \n '

"*\n**\n***" is look like

*

**

***